# What sort of political/economic power did the nobility wield in Victorian-era England?

Tags: economy, politics, royalty

And how did the various titles differ in terms of their influence?

Right now I’m trying to get a better understanding of how European, specifically British, nobility operated and what sorts of duties they had/powers they were afforded. This question is intended for a fantasy story that takes place roughly during the time of the Industrial Revolution rather than the medieval period, but I’ll take any information that might provide clarity or context regardless of the time period.

Some key questions I’d like answered:

-How much more influence and wealth would a duke have compared to a marquess or a count? What about a count to a viscount or a baron?

-Was the hierarchy of titles strictly linear or could you have counts with more power than marquesses or impoverished dukes with less land and wealth to their name than certain well-off viscounts or barons?

-What official duties did the nobility still have during the early modern period?

I know this question may be a bit broad but I’d really appreciate any help or resources that’d give me a clearer picture of how nobles and their houses/peerages functioned day to day.

Comment: You should really ask this on History.SE, if you want the strictly historical answer even if your purpose is writing a story. Use the gathered knowledge as input for devising your own setting, and then you can ask questions for help setting up the fictional parts.

Comment: (1) VTC for what @KeizerHarm said. (2) In England the various hereditary titles of nobility were purely decorative. There was very little difference between a duke, an earl or a baron; as far as the law was concerned, they were all [peers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peerages_in_the_United_Kingdom). (3) There was little distinction in law between a peer and a commoner, but... (4) As peers of Great Britain they had a seat in the [House of Lords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Lords) which is sort-of kind-of the upper house of Parliament, and was vastly more powerful then than now.

Comment: Long story short, the class system of England was (and still is) mostly a matter of social custom and convention; other than having a vote in the House of Lords the nobles could not do anything more than a commoner could. (And in compensation they could not be elected as members of the House of Commons, which in Victorian times was already much more powerful than the House of Lords.)

Comment: @KeizerHarm From the [Help Centre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): 'History: History questions should NOT be about real-world history, unless asking for examples to construct a particular history for a world.' The OP is asking for historical examples to construct their own fantasy world.

Comment: @Otkin I agree with you on OP's motivation with the question, but they are not actually engaging in much construction of their own world within the question body. They are asking for knowledge but not applying it; and I think that part is necessary for a question to be truly said to be world**building** rather than historical research.

Comment: @KeizerHarm This is not necessarily the case. Have you considered that the OP might not be a specialist in history and they are asking this question to create a framework upon which they will construct their fictional society and decide on its mechanics? In other words, they are building a foundation for their world's society. I do not insist that this is exactly the case. But this is one of the possible interpretations of this question.

Comment: @Otkin I try not to assume the questioner's motivations, I only know what has been written in the question body. And in my view the question body does not describe a worldbuilding problem, it just describes what knowledge is required. I think that asking for historical knowledge to solve a problem is a valid WB.SE use case; but for that there needs to be a problem. One can definitely use historical knowledge to work out a framework for one's setting, but the best place to procure historical knowledge - without direct application of said knowledge to a problem - is History.SE, not here.

Comment: @KeizerHarm There is no rule that forbids asking questions that potentially would be a better fit on another stack. You can advise asking elsewhere, but it should not be used as a reason for the closure.

Comment: @Otkin I have not actually voted to close this question, I have just advised the OP to ask it elsewhere. However, the reason I am not voting to reopen is because of the lack of application of historical knowledge to a worldbuilding problem.

Comment: It seems that I am muddleheaded today. Your words were used as a justification for VTCs,, but you did not VTC, indeed. My apologies. My point still stands. This question complies with the WB.SE rules when it comes to being on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of political power the titled aristocrats, and the untitled landed gentry beneath them, had in the UK era declined greatly during the Victorian era from 1837 to 1901.

Each titled nobleman from baron up to Duke, was entitled to a vote in the House of Lords (along with senior clergymen), which was the upper house of the British parliament.  So each could vote on legislation.

Below the titled noblemen were the baronets, who didn't have seats in the House of Lords.

And below the baronets were thousands of landowners of the gentry class who owned large country estates.

I note that all of the family members of a titled nobleman were legally commoners, as were the baronets and their families and the landed gentry and their families.

All commoners who were eligible to vote could run for election to the House of Commons, the other house of parliament.  That included many middle class persons as well as family members of the gentry and nobility.  And the richer someone was, the easier it was to get elected.

At the beginning of the 19th century the number of representatives that each country district and town had in the House of Commons hadn't been changed for centuries.  Many new towns with large populations had no representation.  Other towns had become ghost towns, but still kept their representation, and landowers who owned large prts of those "pocket boroughs" or "rotten boroughs" could nominated who they wanted and make certain they were elected.

So the nobles and landed gentry had a lot of control and influence over the government, shared with the upper middle classes.

It was assumed that a prime minister would be a member of the landowning gentry, and most of them were titled noblemen or members of their families.
When future prime minister Benajmin Disraeli went into politics, his political allies loaned a lot of money to Disreli's father to buy a country estate, Hugenden Manor, so Disraeli could be a country gentleman suited for representing a country district.

During the 19th century the landed class gradually lost more and more power over the government and the UK came closer and closer to being a democracy.

The Great Reform Reform Act in 1832k abolished rotten boroughs and redistbuted parliamentary seats, as well as extending the right to vote.

In about 1845-55 county police forces were established, diminishing the control of the local gentry over law enforcement.

in 1846 the "Corn Las" that protected agriculture from foreign competition  and kept food priceshigh were repealed.

The Second Reform act in 1867 doubled the number of men who could vote, extending it to working class voters for the first time.

Competitive exams for the civil service were introduced in 1870, mking it harder for upper class officials to hire their unqulified relatives and friends.

Local school boards, the members elected by voters, were established starting in 1870 to provide free eleementary education for all children. Education became less and less a monopoly of the upper and middle casses.

The right to buy and sell commissisons in the army was abolished in 1871.

In 1872 the Ballot Act allowed secret voting, so someone's employer or landlord could not punish them for how they voted.

Elected county councils to run local government were introduced in 1888.

And so on during the rest of the Victorian era, and into the 20th century, restricting the control of the country gentry, that the titled nobles were the apex of, over the government.

The only politcal power which Victorian era British titled noblemen had was the power to vote in the House of Lords.

At the start of the Victorian era the country gentry, of which the titled nobles were the highest rank, had a great deal of control and influence over the national government and local government bodies.  And that control and influence over government affairs stedily waned as government became more democratic, bureaucratic, and professional.

But the landed gentry and the titled noblemen above them still had a lot of social respect and deference at the end of the period.